# How to add year parameter to SQL query?

Tags: sql, parameters, sql-server-2014

I'm creating a report to compare sales of two years using crystal reports.I need to add Year parameter to filter the data by entering to years to CurrentYear Parameter and PreviousYear Parameter.How can I do this?

I tried below query, but the problem is how to add parameter to aggregate function?

```
DECLARE @CompareYear varchar(50),
@CurrentYear varchar(50)

SELECT 
    ISNULL(sp.Telephone,'No Sales Employee'),
    od.CardCode,
    od.CardName,
    Sum(case when Year(od.DocDate)=@CompareYear then od.DocTotal else 0 end) as Sold2018,
    Sum(case when Year(od.DocDate)=@CurrentYear then od.DocTotal else 0 end) as Sold2019
FROM
    ORDR od
Left Join OSLP sp
    On od.SlpCode=sp.SlpCode
Group By
    sp.Telephone,
    od.CardCode,
    od.CardName
having(Sum(case when Year(od.DocDate)=@CompareYear then od.DocTotal else 0 end) < Sum(case when Year(od.DocDate)=@CurrentYear then od.DocTotal else 0 end))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly catch your aim, you need to add `YEAR(od.DocDate)` both on `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` clauses.